# Is the sentence: "The longer I worked, the worse my career." A correct sentence?

Tags: grammar

In the English translation of Cixin Liu's *The Three-Body Problem* by Ken Liu there is the sentence in chapter sixteen, *The Three Body Problem*, that reads:

> The longer I worked, the worse my career.

Which to me feels like an incomplete sentence: the worse my career [__ what? __]? Perhaps it could be helped with a `became` -or- a `got`? I went back to look at the original sentence which just says:

> 越混越次

It's an acceptable translation, but sounds very chinglish-y.

Is this a proper sentence?

Answer (score 1):

*The longer I worked, the worse my career* is an example of what is usually called a *double comparative*. Such comparatives most commonly contain parallel structures, either with or without verbs. For example in clichés such as:

> - The bigger they come, the harder they fall.
> - The sooner, the better.

In your example there is faulty parallelism: a verb is missing in the second part. While its meaning is clear, it is grammatically questionable.

There is a good article about *double comparatives* on *ThoughtCo*:

https://www.thoughtco.com/double-comparatives-1210274

Answer (score -1):

The sentence needs a predicate, depending on the context:
The longer I worked, the worse my career was.
Or: The longer I worked, the worse my career has been.

Comment: Try and cite a source in support of the answer.